# What's the easiest way to automatically backup my phone's data?

Tags: backup

My goal is to have backups of my phone (Samsung Galaxy S3) created regularly and automatically.

In case it get's lost or stolen, or damaged or reset to factory mode, I would like by one click to recover (at the same or an other phone) the current data:

- App-settings
- E-Mails
- SMS
- Contacts
- Apps
- Phone customizations (language, desktop widgets, background...)
- Photos/Video
- Mp3-Data

I prefer the backup to be at my computer, but I do not mind backing up in a cloud if it is provided by a bigger company.

Comment: If you are rooted a Nandroid backup is the most complete backup you could possibly do, otherwise you should try Titanium backup

Comment: Thanks. Is it recommenadble to root ones phone?

Comment: As to your question whether rooting is to be recommended: depends on, you might wish to take a look at our [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) and the information linked from there. Concerning your original question: What OS are you using on your computer?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Most phones have a back up and reset option in settings. I went to that and clicked on everything I wanted backed up. I backed up everything to my Sd and E-mail.. (Google servers)..